# Magento - Update Cart On Quantity Change Not Working

Tags: php, magento

I have added in quantity increment buttons to the cart:

[image]

These work to increase the quantity in the qty box,

However I want the whole cart to update each time they press either increase or decrease,

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Reece

Comment: "Whole cart to update" means that you want quantity for each product to increase or simply the changes made by you are directly updated to cart.

Comment: Each time you press the up or down arrow, I need the cart to update to reflect the new quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make an Ajax call and execute the following functionality:-

```
   // Product ID and Quantity
    $pid = $_REQUEST['productId'];
    $qnt = $_REQUEST['qty'];
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $items = $cart->getItems(); 
    foreach ($items as $item) :
        if($pid == $item->getId()) :
            echo $item->getQty();
            $item->setQty($qnt); 
            $cart->save();
        endif;
    endforeach;
```

This is just an example, you need to manage the variables according to your need. Whenever button is press just make a ajax call and update cart and then you need to update it via Ajax in other place where you want. Above code provide you the way to save product quantity to cart.